# React Native Flex: 1 Does not fill whole screen

Tags: react-native, flexbox

I tried to fill the whole screen with black using `flex: 1`. but the result is like this

[image: resuls in iphone simulator]

[image: result in my android devices]

```
  <View
    style={{
      flex: 1,
      backgroundColor: 'black',
    }}
  />
```

i've also tried using:

```
   height: '100%',
   width: '100%',
```

and

```
const HEIGHT = Dimensions.get('window').height;
const WIDTH = Dimensions.get('window').width;
```

but the result is still the same.

is there a way to completely fill the whole screen?

Comment: It is because you're using device with notch

Comment: what more area do you want to cover?

Comment: @KaranMehta my android devices doesn't use notch

Comment: @GauravRoy notice there are still some white around the screen top, right, bottom, and right

Comment: Then upload picture of android device as well

Comment: @KaranMehta i've upload the android device picture

Comment: @Raihan Try wrapping your `View` inside `SafeAreaView` and add your background styling to `SafeAreaView`. Also you will need to set the status bar to translucent or set black colour to it.

Comment: @Raihan Are you wrapping your component with react navigation or this is the parent component only?

Comment: @MayankJain yes im wrapping it in react navigation

Comment: @Raihan Then try this const                                                            
ReactNavigation = require('react-navigation');
ReactNavigation.SafeAreaView.setStatusBarHeight(0);

Answer (score 2):

Are you wrapping your app inside safe area view, anyway you can use percentage width and heights to fill the entire screen if flex:1 is not working.

```
style = {{ width:'100%', height:'100%' }}
```

Comment: i've tried your suggestion and the result is still the same. and correct me if im wrong, doesn't save area view only work for IOS 11 or above?

Answer (score 2):

First import:

```
import { StatusBar } from "react-native";
import { SafeAreaView } from "react-native-safe-area-context";
```

Change your layout to:

```
<StatusBar backgroundColor="black" barStyle="white-content"/>
<SafeAreaView 
    style={{
        flex: 1,
        backgroundColor: 'black',
    }}
>
      <View>...</View>
</SafeAreaView>
```

Comment: And bottom backgroundColor have to set tabBarComponent style below.  const tabBar = createBottomTabNavigator({...}, { style: {backgroundColor: 'black} })

Answer (score 1):

Try this if you are using react navigation

```
const ReactNavigation = require('react-navigation');
ReactNavigation.SafeAreaView.setStatusBarHeight(0);
```

or

```
navigationOptions: {
  headerForceInset: {top: 'never'},
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First wrap your view component in SafeAreaView then provide a flex style to it.

```
<SafeAreaView style={{flex: 1}}>
    <View style={/* do your styling */}>...</View>
</SafeAreaView>
```

Answer (score 1):

make sure parent element also have flex:1

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You can user Dimensions.get('window') to get the full height and width of the screen.

declare a const

```
const HEIGHT = Dimensions.get('window').height;
const WIDTH = Dimensions.get('window').width;
```

then use this inside style

```
style = {{
            height = HEIGHT,
            width = WIDTH,
            backgroundColor = 'black',
        }}
```

Comment: i've tried using this method but the results are the same

Answer (score 0):

I have had similar problem. But in my case, I have solved the problem by modifying View to SafeAreaView in App.js (especially return() session) and other related files.

Answer (score -1):

If you given padding of parent view, so remove it. May be it work and Your render function it should be like this.

```
render() {
  return (
   <View style={{ flex: 1, backgroundColor: 'black'}} />
  )
}
```

Comment: as you can see in above i don't have any padding in my code.

Comment: render() {
    return (
      <View
        style={{
          flex: 1,
          backgroundColor: 'black',
        }}
      />
    );
  }

Comment: it's literally the same with yours